# Retrieve true color of image with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, colors, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I've tried multiple Node Packages for retrieving colors, they all work for getting a color, and indeed a color like the one of the image, but the color is a bit darker and off from the real true color of it.

I've tried the following node modules: **jpeg-js**, **pngjs**, **dominant-color**, **imagecolors**, and some others.

But they all have the same problem, this is the result:

[image: Real color of image compared with color extracted with code]

Edit 1:

I've also tried to do it directly with ImageMagick, but same problem:

```
convert test2.jpg -scale 1x1\! -format '%[pixel:u]' info:-
rgb(210,133,55) (This is #D28537)
```

Edit 2:

I also just tried an online tool: [imagecolorpicker.com](http://imagecolorpicker.com) and it gets me #DB8A44 which is almost exactly like #DB8A42, but I want to do it with my own code I have like 5,000 images to analyze.

Edit 3:

I just tried with PHP

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$colores = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
```

And again... wrong color.

Comment: How do you get these color-values? If I use a color-picker, I get `#E7862D` on the left, and `#DD8119` on the right. And what exactly is your input image? And are you aware that jpeg-images are lossy and therefore they can distort the color values from the input image.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I'm aware. And the true color is #DB8A42, I drawed it Illustrator. The square on the right is the color that all color-extraction codes spit out. I also just tried an online tool: https://imagecolorpicker.com/ and it gets me #DB8A44 which is almost exactly like #DB8A42

Comment: @CarlosC I have the same issue using get-image-colors npm package in nodejs. may I know how you resolved it

Answer (score 0):

How did you create your original test.png? Does it have a profile? What version of Imagemagick are you using?

The following works fine for me in IM 6.9.9.40 Q16 Mac OSX.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:"#DB8A42" test.png
```

[image]

```
convert test.png -scale 1x1! txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (56283,35466,16962)  #DB8A42  srgb(219,138,66)
```

or in current versions of Imagemagick:

```
convert test.png -scale 1x1! -format "%[hex:u.p{0,0}]" info:
DB8A42
```

This also works:

```
convert test.png -scale 1x1! -format "%[pixel:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
srgb(219,138,66)

convert xc:"srgb(219,138,66)" -depth 8 txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (56283,35466,16962)  #DB8A42  srgb(219,138,66)
```

My guess is that you have an old version of Imagemagick and may need an upgrade.

Comment: I actually didn't create the color. It's a PDF with lot's of colors in a grid converted into PNG to then analyze and get the values of every single color of the PDF. You are saying I must convert the PDF to PNG in a certain way? It's weird that the www.imagecolorpicker.com site does get it "correctly"

Comment: You are right. That site does not work correctly on my swatch. Try some other color picker. One other note is that JPG is not a good format, if you want constant color. It is lossy compressed in blocks. The value you get may not be exactly what you specified. I created the same image in jpg output format. `convert -size 100x100 xc:"#DB8A42" test.jpg`. I looked at it in a tool similar to Photoshop (GraphicConvert on the Mac) and the colors are constant but at values of 218,138,65. I am not saying you need to use PNG, but PDF files may have imbedded raster images, which could be JPG